# Lost window in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am new and stupid. I closed this window:

[image]

How this window is called and how to activate it. Make it pop up.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is the [`Locals window`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6td98xe%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

You will find it under Debug -> Windows.

Alternatively, use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl + D + L</kbd>.

It is only available during a debugging session and is not available on Express editions.

Comment: It ceases to amaze me why Microsoft haven't put all of the views under the view menu...

Answer (score 11):

Go to the Debug menu then windows then locals and it will show up.  You must be in the middle of debugging to have it show in the list.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The Locals window comes up with you start debugging (hit F5).  If you need it back, go to Debug > Windows > Locals while debugging.

Note, you can also get it back if you click Windows > Reset Window Layout (which I've had to use on occasion when windows get really messed up!)  Be warned that this will erase any changes you've made to the layout.  But sometimes it is worth it!